# Forwarding arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I have a construct in a form:

```
template<class T>
    void do_something_with_it(T*&& ptr)
    {
//here I can do something with this ptr
    }

    template<class T,class... Args>
    void do_something_with_them(T*&& ptr, Args&&... args)
    {
        do_something_with_it(std::forward<T&&>(ptr));
        do_something_with_them(std::forward<Args&&>(args)...);
    }
```

but for some reason I cannot forward those arguments. Is there a way to do it?
I'm using gcc 4.6.1.

Comment: What does perfect pointer forwarding gain you, if I may ask?

Comment: #FredOverflow perfect forwarding pointer perhaps nothing but perfect forwarding parameter packs of pointers surely does, or doesn't it. By the way, I'm just trying to learn this stuff so I'm more than happy to listen to every opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that you get compile time errors, because `T*&&` is *not* a perfect forwarding vehicle. Only `T&&` is. So your `ptr` parameter *only accepts rvalues*. And in addition to that, your `std::forward<T&&>` should be `std::forward<T*>`, but of course now that you have the other error anyway this is irrelevant. And in addition to *that* the call to `do_something_with_them` misses to hit a base case of `do_something_with_them` with zero parameters, because if `args` is empty...

If you really only want to accepts pointers, you can work with `enable_if` and `is_same` or `is_convertible`. But then of course I don't think it's "forwarding" anymore. What about

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
auto do_something_with_them(T&&t, Args&&...args)
  -> decltype(do_something_with_it(std::forward<T>(t)))
{ ... }
```

That way you let `do_something_with_it` decide whether or not it accepts the argument (if you want you can put the recursive call into that `decltype` too. I leave it as an exercise to the reader as to what operator might be needed here). But of course `do_something_with_it` has the same problem too about not being generic.